# Channel Images and Stash

Tags: stash, channel-images

I'm having an issue w/ Stash and Channel Images where the image:url isn't being stashed at all, but everything else is. Here's the first portion of my index.html so you can see what is being set w/ stash:set_list

**Index.html**:

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_1}" parse="inward"}

    {!--  ============================================
    TEST COLLECTION
    ================================================== --}

    {case value="test-collection"}

        {exp:stash:set_value name="page_content" value="{exp:stash:embed:partials:collection_thumbs}"}

        {!-- cache the list of articles in a given category for 60 minutes --}
        {exp:stash:set_list 
            name="collection:{segment_2}" 
            parse_tags="yes"
            parse_depth="2"
            save="yes" 
            scope="site" 
            refresh="60" 
            replace="no"
        }

            {exp:channel:entries
                channel="artworks"
                disable="categories|category_fields|member_data"
                status="open"
                limit="36"
                paginate="bottom"
            }

                {stash:page_category}{exp:channel:category_heading channel="artworks"}{category_name}{/exp:channel:category_heading}{/stash:page_category}

                {stash:page_title}<small>Collection / </small> {exp:stash:get name="page_category"}{/stash:page_title}

                {!-- Meta Properties --}
                {stash:head_title}{exp:stash:get name="page_category"} | {site_label}{/stash:head_title}
                {stash:meta_type}reelizer:collection{/stash:meta_type}
                {stash:canonical_url}{segment_1}/{segment_2}{/stash:canonical_url}
                {stash:meta_description}{exp:stash:get name="page_category"} Collection on {site_label}.{/stash:meta_description}
                {stash:meta_image}{gv_cdn_url}img/meta-image.png{/stash:meta_image}
                {stash:twitter_card_content}summary{/stash:twitter_card_content}
                {stash:entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry_id}

                {exp:channel_images:images entry_id="{entry_id}"}
                    {stash:artwork_url}{url_title_path=artwork}{/stash:artwork_url}
                    {stash:artwork_artist}{artworks_artist}{title}{/stash:artwork_artist}
                    {stash:artwork_title}{title}{/stash:artwork_title}                          
                    {stash:artwork_image_small}{image:url:small}{/stash:artwork_image_small}    
                {/exp:channel_images:images}

                {paginate}
                    {stash:pagination}
                        {sn_pagination}
                    {/stash:pagination} 
                {/paginate}

            {/exp:channel:entries}

        {/exp:stash:set_list}

    {/case}
....
```

Notice I'm storing a value in the Channel Images block for the img url: {stash:artwork_image_small}{image:url:small}{/stash:artwork_image_small}

But for some reason my collection_thumbs partial is pulling all the correct values except for {artwork_image_small}. It should be outputting the URL, but is instead just outputting {artwork_image_small}. Here's my code for the collection_thumbs partial:

**collection_thumbs**:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="collection:{segment_2}"}
<div class="artwork small" id="artwork-">
    <a href="{artwork_url}" rel="bookmark" >    
        <div class="description">
            <span class="title">{artwork_artist}</span>         
            <span class="divider"></span>                                
            <p><em>{artwork_title}</em></p>                             
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <img width="300" height="225" src="{artwork_image_small}" class="thumb" alt="{artwork_title}">  
    </a>
</div>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

What am I missing? Thanks for any help you guys can provide!

Comment: I realize this is old, but I am getting a page with Stash and Channel Images working. I used the Channel Image field name and not the exp:channel_images:somefieldname tag. 

Did you ever get this working? If so, how? If not do you still need help?